# S3 On CM 14.1: Made SD Internal Storage, Reversed, Now "Empty" Internal Shared Storage On PC

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, internal-storage, sd-card

I have a Galaxy S3 on CM 14.1 (Android 7.1.1).  I formatted the SD Card as internal storage.  Then I couldn't access my internal storage from my PC, so I switched back.  I formatted the SD Card to portable storage.

Now, my internal storage (now listed as "internal shared storage") is "empty" when I connect it to my PC.  I've tried:

- wiping data, cache, and reinstalling CM 14.1
- taking out my SD Card
- reconnecting to PC as PTP, etc.
- using another USB cable, port, etc.
- restarting multiple times

Nothing seems to work.  What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing the following on Clockworkmod Recovery:

- Clearing all caches (go to mount/unmount --> clear all caches (system, etc.))
- Unmounting, then mounting everything (System, SD Card, Media, etc.)
- Format SD Card (from CWM).  (then I had to restart to connect SD Card with CM 14.1 zip file).
- Reinstalling CM 14.1

Now I finally have the internal storage and portable SD Card formatted correctly.